# How to get Custom Attributes in Carts Item REST API?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

End Point: `/rest/V1/carts/mine/`

Added Custom Attribute Name: Unit

Type: Dropdown

Response:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "created_at": "2019-10-19 10:23:20",
  "updated_at": "2019-11-01 09:27:51",
  "is_active": true,
  "is_virtual": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": 9,
      "sku": "Test",
      "qty": 1,
      "name": "Test",
      "price": 100,
      "product_type": "simple",
      "quote_id": "10",
      "extension_attributes": {
        "item_weight": 500
      }
    }
  ],
  "items_count": 1,
  "items_qty": 1,
  "customer": {
    "id": 5,
    "group_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-10-19 10:23:18",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-01 12:51:21",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "test@testmail.com",
    "firstname": "elan",
    "lastname": "m",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "customer_id": 5,
        "region": {
          "region_code": "TN",
          "region": "Tamil Nadu",
          "region_id": 563
        },
        "region_id": 563,
        "country_id": "IN",
        "street": [
          "chrnnai"
        ],
        "telephone": "8678944602",
        "postcode": "600096",
        "city": "chennai",
        "firstname": "elan",
        "lastname": "m"
      }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "is_subscribed": false
    }
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "id": 499,
    "region": null,
    "region_id": null,
    "region_code": null,
    "country_id": null,
    "street": [
      ""
    ],
    "telephone": null,
    "postcode": null,
    "city": null,
    "firstname": null,
    "lastname": null,
    "customer_id": 5,
    "email": "test@testmail.com",
    "same_as_billing": 0,
    "save_in_address_book": 0
  },
  "orig_order_id": 0,
  "currency": {
    "global_currency_code": "INR",
    "base_currency_code": "INR",
    "store_currency_code": "INR",
    "quote_currency_code": "INR",
    "store_to_base_rate": 0,
    "store_to_quote_rate": 0,
    "base_to_global_rate": 1,
    "base_to_quote_rate": 1
  },
  "customer_is_guest": false,
  "customer_note_notify": true,
  "customer_tax_class_id": 3,
  "store_id": 1,
  "extension_attributes": {
    "shipping_assignments": [
      {
        "shipping": {
          "address": {
            "id": 297,
            "region": null,
            "region_id": null,
            "region_code": null,
            "country_id": null,
            "street": [
              ""
            ],
            "telephone": null,
            "postcode": null,
            "city": null,
            "firstname": null,
            "lastname": null,
            "customer_id": 5,
            "email": "test@testmail.com",
            "same_as_billing": 0,
            "save_in_address_book": 0
          },
          "method": null
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "item_id": 9,
            "sku": "Test",
            "qty": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "price": 100,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "quote_id": "10",
            "extension_attributes": {
              "item_weight": 500
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need an Custom Attribute in each item.